# Remove letterings from Specialized Sirrus 4.0

Tags: specialized-bikes, decals

I'm planning to get myself a [Specialized Sirrus 4.0](https://www.specialized.com/at/de/sirrus-4-0/p/174696?color=279693-174696) and really like the overall look of the Specialized lettering and painting.

But what really bothers me are the '**4.0**' and '**Sirrus**' letterings on the frame. Does anybody have this bike and can tell me something about the composition and if it is somehow possible to remove those without destroying the painting underneath?

Unfortunately I couldn't find any answers to my questions in this specific case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually there is a layer of clearcoat over the decals, so removing the decals requires removing the clearcoat, either by sanding or chemical stripping. People have done this, but it's a lot of work and is error-prone, since you're likely to take some of the underlying paint off too.

It's unlikely but possible that there's no finish on top of these decals, in which case you could probably scrape them off with a plastic knife. Ask the dealer.

Answer (score 2):

At least "4.0" looks like a tiny writing at the rear of the frame. If you just do not like 4 (I know it is an unhappy number in some cultures), put there a small well-looking sticker you see as more appropriate.

Comment: I like this last bit of advice. I always had a used bike and did something or other to decorate it, usually a band or LBS sticker. It helps you recognize YOUR Specialized bike out of a sea of bikes. You could also put a piece of electric tape close to the shade of the finish over the bits you want to cover.